# How do I extract a gallery image from databse?

Tags: gallery

I am using [Tribulant Gallery Voting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-voting/) to have a Pet contest on my website.

The plugin adds a Vote button below each image in the gallery.

I want to show the 'Top 5' Pet photos with most votes in the sidebar.

My friend has written some code that extracts Votes, image id, title and description from the Tribulent gallery voting database table and sorts them in descending order (most votes first)

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT attachment_id, COUNT(attachment_id) AS qty FROM wp_5vt0txsx66_galleryvotes GROUP BY attachment_id ORDER BY qty DESC" );

  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr><td>Qty</td><td>image_id</td><td>Project Title</td><td>Project Description</td></tr>";

  foreach ($result as $row)
  {
 echo "<tr>";

 echo "<td>".$row->qty."</td><td>".$row->attachment_id."</td>";

 $attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment($row->attachment_id);

 echo "<td>".$attachment_meta['title']."</td>";

 echo "<td>".$attachment_meta['caption']."</td>";

 echo "</tr>";
 }

 echo "</table>";

 function wp_get_attachment( $attachment_id ) {

 $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );

 return array(

      'alt' => get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ),

      'caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt,

      'description' => $attachment->post_content,

      'href' => get_permalink( $attachment->ID ),

      'src' => $attachment->guid,

      'title' => $attachment->post_title

 );

}
```

Here Qty represents Votes.

The above code displays the following output in the sidebar :
[image]

I want to show the Image itself in place of image_id. Can anyone please guide me how to get the images from the database and display them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [get_attachment_image()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image):

```
$att_markup = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
```

Or [get_attachment_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link):

```
$att_link = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
```